# Solving FO ODE: optimal approach

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have such ODE: $$(2x^2+8y^2)dx + 2002xydy=0$$. My attemps were when I assumed that $u = \frac{y}{x}$ and next time $v = \frac{x}{y}$ but I didn't came up with a solution. So now I'm asking for help.

Comment: In the future, it would be nice to see your attempts with the substitutions you tried. This would help show us that you tried to solve on your own, as well as help us give better advice if you were on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by rewriting this as $8y^2 + 2002xyy' = -2x^2.$

Now, look at our two $y$ terms. We have a $y^2$ and a $yy' = \frac12 (y^2)'.$ So, we can make the substitution $u = y^2$ to linearize our equation:

$$8u + 1001xu' = -2x^2$$

(you can also arrive at this substitution by applying the technique for [Bernoulli equations](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/bernoulli.aspx), which is how I figured out to do it)

From here, you should be able to solve using techniques for first-order linear ODEs. I suggest the integration factor method, but you can also solve this using the principle of superposition and the fact that the homogeneous equation is separable.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The equation $(2x^2+8y^2)\mathrm{d}x+2002xy\mathrm{d}x=0$ is equivalent to the equation $$y'=-\frac{1001xy}{x^2+4y^2}.$$ This is a homogeneous equation, as $$y'=-\frac{1001xy}{x^2[1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2]}=-\frac{1001\frac{y}{x}}{1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}.$$ Let $xz=y$, with $y'=xz'+z$, hence $$xz'+z=-\frac{1001z}{1+z^2}.$$ Now we can write $$xz'=-\frac{z^3+1002z}{z^2+1},$$ which is separable. There are two cases here: $z=0$ and $z\neq0$. The case with $z=0$ is trivial, and for $z\neq0$, we separate: $$\frac{z^2+1}{z(z^2+1002)}z'=-\frac{1}{x}.$$ A trick for the partial fraction decomposition here is $$\frac{z^2+1}{z(z^2+1002)}=\frac{z^3+z}{z^2(z^2+1002)}=\frac{1002(z^3+z)}{1002z^2(z^2+1002)}=\frac{[(z^2+1002)-z^2](z^3+z)}{1002z^2(z^2+1002)}=\frac{z^3+z}{1002z^2}-\frac{z^3+z}{1002(z^2+1002)}=\frac{z}{1002}+\frac{1}{1002z}-\frac{z^3+1002z-1001z}{1002(z^2+1002)}=\frac{1}{1002z}+\frac{1001z}{1002(z^2+1002)}=\frac{1}{1002z}+\frac{1001}{2004}\frac{2z}{z^2+1002}.$$ To integrate, there are four cases to consider: $z\lt0,x\lt0$; $z\lt0,x\gt0$; $z\gt0,x\lt0$; $z\gt0,x\gt0$. Antidifferentiating respectively, one gets that $$\ln(-z)+\frac{1001}{2004}\ln(z^2+1002)=-\ln(-x)+A,$$ $$\ln(-z)+\frac{1001}{2004}\ln(z^2+1002)=-\ln(x)+B,$$ $$\ln(z)+\frac{1001}{2004}\ln(z^2+1002)=-\ln(-x)+C,$$ $$\ln(z)+\frac{1001}{2004}\ln(z^2+1002)=-\ln(x)+D.$$ Applying the exponential function gives $$-z(z^2+1002)^{\frac{1001}{2004}}=-\frac{a}{x},$$ $$-z(z^2+1002)^{\frac{1001}{2004}}=\frac{b}{x},$$ $$z(z^2+1002)^{\frac{1001}{2004}}=-\frac{c}{x},$$ $$z(z^2+1002)^{\frac{1001}{2004}}=\frac{d}{x}$$ with $a,b,c,d\gt0$. This can be simplified further, by simply having two cases: $x\lt0$ and $x\gt0$, giving respectively $$z(z^2+1002)^{\frac{1001}{2004}}=-\frac{\alpha}{x},$$ $$z(z^2+1002)^{\frac{1001}{2004}}=\frac{\beta}{x},$$ with $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$, including the trivial solution. Unfortunately, I do not believe one can solve for $z$ algebraically any further. Here, we undo the substitution $y=xz$, so $$\frac{y}{x}\left[\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2+1002\right]^{\frac{1001}{2004}}=-\frac{\alpha}{x},$$ $$\frac{y}{x}\left[\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2+1002\right]^{\frac{1001}{2004}}=\frac{\beta}{x},$$ simplifying to $$\frac{y(y^2+1002x^2)^{\frac{1001}{2004}}}{-x\cdot{x^{\frac{1001}{1002}}}}=-\frac{\alpha}{x},$$ $$\frac{y(y^2+1002x^2)^{\frac{1001}{2004}}}{x\cdot{x^{\frac{1001}{1002}}}}=\frac{\beta}{x},$$ simplifying even further to $$\frac{y(y^2+1002x^2)^{\frac{1001}{2004}}}{x^{\frac{1001}{1002}}}=\alpha,$$ $$\frac{y(y^2+1002x^2)^{\frac{1001}{2004}}}{x^{\frac{1001}{1002}}}=\beta.$$ This is the most one can simplify for an answer. I am curious as to why you said the substitution did not work when you tried it, though. You did not show any work you attempted nor did you clarify, so I believe you likely made some algebraic mistake on the way.